# VK API примеры запросов

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests, вконтакте, postman

Вот недавно начал изучать API VK. Некоторые методы плохо описаны или вообще не так работают. Хочу узнать есть ли какой-то ресурс сайт/статья или etc с примерами запросов. Можно на любом языке, но преимущественно (python, requests, javascript, postman, etc)

Пытался сам опробовать некоторые методы, но не всегда понятен ответ запросов, а в документации ответы некоторых методов вообще не описаны.

Answer (score 0):

*Достаточно пользоваться ВК 1 год, и изучать API VK. Всё приходит со временем. На данный момент, я искал список запросов, но их в открытом доступе в интернете нет, (вероятнее всего, ВК запретил копирайт)*

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: спасибо, понял!

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ